# Automate Loop based in how many the user want in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My professor asked me to simulate Boolean Gates and the output is a truth table

To simulate an n=3 Gates you need 3 for loop

```
for i in range(0,2):
     for j in range(0,2): 
           for k in range(0,2):
                 stuff
```

To simulate an n=2 Gates you need 2 for loop

```
for i in range(0,2):
     for j in range(0,2): 
                 stuff
```

i wanted to have an an n= user input, so there may be a chance where the user input more than 10
is there a way to automate the loop??

if there's any reference, especially if it uses an oop paradigm, it would be very helpfull
Thank you

Comment: my idea was to do a recursive loop, is it possible??

Comment: if I understand you, n changes the loop count by `2**n`, if so you can just change the loop range by that equation. unless you use the loop count in `stuff`

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `itertools.product`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to generate all the possible `2**n` combinations of values for `i,j,k,...`. If that is the case, you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate them all:

```
from itertools import product

for p in product(range(2), repeat=3):
    print(p)
```

Which will produce:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
```

Simply change `repeat=n` and you are done.

Cheers!